# The principal branch of the logarithm. Find the range of $\theta$.

Tags: complex-analysis

The principal branch of the logarithm.

Let $Ω = ℂ\setminus(−∞, 0]$.

Then $\log_Ω ^{} = \log() + $ where $ > 0,  ∈ (−, ).$

Could you give me an explanation why  $ ∈ (−, )$ ?

I don't get how I am supposed to find the range of $\theta$.  Thanks.

Comment: $e^{i \theta} \in \Omega$ **iff** $\theta \notin \{ -n \pi \mid n \text{ odd} \}$.

Comment: Because we use the principal mesure of the angle. In my opinion, it is just an agreement between mathematicians and nothing more.